# How to loop through XmlDocument and return a csv?

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I am trying to loop through an `XmlDocument` object and return a reasonable csv.

I am able to traverse all nodes using recursion

```
private StringBuilder findAllnodes(XmlNode node, StringBuilder buf) {
        foreach (XmlNode n in node.ChildNodes) {
            findAllnodes(n, buf);
            if (n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) {
                buf.AppendFormat("{0}",n.InnerText.Trim());
            }
            else {
                buf.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}", n.Name, n.InnerText.Trim());
            }
        }
        return buf;
    }
```

and write the values to a string, but it just isn't coming out correctly.

The XML string I am trying to parse has n number of Key Value pairs (which could get quite long) and a possibility for multiple repeated sections.  Here is an example:

Is there something quick and easy out there? I was really hoping for somekind of Native library as I felt this would be a quite common remedial task.

**UPDATE:  Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap:Body>
    <perfOCRResp xmlns="http://com.speedMonkey.getthatmoney.pitt.edu">
        <perfOCRResults>
            <status>SUCCESS</status>
            <clientID>testApp</clientID>
            <outputs>
                <ocrOut>
                    <clientID>testApp</clientID>
                    <isSuccess>true</isSuccess>
                    <message>SUCESS</message>
                    <classificTemp>monkeyTemp</classificTemp>
                    <recogVals>
                        <KeyValue>
                            <key>tempCode</key>
                            <value>NLN000001</value>
                        </KeyValue>
                        <KeyValue>
                            <key>tempName</key>
                            <value>monkeyNote</value>
                        </KeyValue>
                        <KeyValue>
                            <key>tempCode</key>
                            <value>NLN000001</value>
                        </KeyValue>
                        <KeyValue>
                            <key>Borrower</key>
                            <value>Monkey See</value>
                        </KeyValue>
                        <KeyValue>
                            <key>solute</key>
                            <value>MonkeyDue</value>
                        </KeyValue>
                        <KeyValue>
                            <key>whatsThis</key>
                            <value>who cares</value>
                        </KeyValue>
                        <KeyValue>
                            <key>solute</key>
                            <value>NLN000001</value>
                        </KeyValue>
                        <KeyValue>
                            <key>imageID</key>
                            <value>thatImage</value>
                        </KeyValue>
                    </recogVals>
                </ocrOut>
            <outputs>
        </perfOCRResults>
    </perfOCRResp>
</soap:Body
```

ocrout can repeat multiple times.  I don't know if you can tell, but there can be an indeterminate amount of key-value pairs in there.  That is one of the reasons I thought traversing through recursively might be the best bet.   But like I said, I am getting to all the nodes, but it is just ugly and without order.  Not the best CSV ever written.  Wishing there was a simple library like there is for JSON.

Comment: It is rather easy to convert an xml into a csv file. Can you show us a small portion of the xml and of the output you want and the current output so we can see where you are going wrong ?

Comment: LINQ-to-XML (`XDocument`) generally provides easier to read code as you can read XML in sequence of rows and than serialize them to whatever you want...

Comment: I honestly see no need for recursion for this. Recursion tends to be something that is over-valued in CS classes but in the real world is almost never very useful. I second the Linq to XML for this. It's much simpler.

Comment: I got to say, I have always found linq-to-xml more difficult to grasp then simply traversing through nodes.  Maybe I need more practice.  Update coming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly look at doing this with LINQ-to-XML. It's much simpler. Here's the code:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://com.speedMonkey.getthatmoney.pitt.edu");
var csv =
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        doc
            .Descendants(ns + "KeyValue")
            .Select(e => String.Format("{0},{1}",
                e.Element(ns + "key").Value.Trim(),
                e.Element(ns + "value").Value.Trim())));
```

The result I get is:

```
tempCode,NLN000001
tempName,monkeyNote
tempCode,NLN000001
Borrower,Monkey See
solute,MonkeyDue
whatsThis,who cares
solute,NLN000001
imageID,thatImage
```

Comment: ill tool around with that.  Thanks.

Comment: btw... Error 6 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments 
Error 7 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: @DmainEvent - what version of .NET are you using? The latest version at least has an enumerable overload.

Comment: this would be 4.5 if I am not mistaken... And I am building in 3.5

Comment: @DmainEvent - Just add `.ToArray()` at the end if the enumerable.